# How to properly import firebase module in React JS to initializeApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to initialize a firebase app but I don't understand how or where to call it.

I have a file name fire.tsx and inside it there's a call to firebase's `initializeApp`. But now what? How do I include this in my app?

I thought just by adding `import { firebaseApp, firebaseAnalytics } from './fire';` to the top of App.tsx it would work but apparently it doesn't. Am I doing this wrong?

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx-xx-xx",
  authDomain: "xxx-xx-xx",
  databaseURL: "xxx-xx-xx",
  projectId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  storageBucket: "xxx-xx-xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  appId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  measurementId: "xxx-xx-xx"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
export default firebaseApp;

export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics();
```

App.tsx

```
import { firebaseApp, firebaseAnalytics } from './fire';
```

[image: Firebase Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the new Modular SDK only because the compat version would be removed in future updates. Try refactoring the code this way:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx-xx-xx",
  authDomain: "xxx-xx-xx",
  databaseURL: "xxx-xx-xx",
  projectId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  storageBucket: "xxx-xx-xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  appId: "xxx-xx-xx",
  measurementId: "xxx-xx-xx"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
```

The new Modular SDK checks if a default instance is already create so you don't have to like in previous versions.

Comment: that works, thanks. With that context I found this documentation that might help someone in the future https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade