# I am getting an error when i was making a new react - native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.initializeApp is not a function

This is a error which is coming when I am making a new react - native app

CODE :

```js
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/database';

class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() { 
        this.checkIfLoggedIn();
    };


    checkIfLoggedIn = () => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('DashboardScreen')
            } else {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
            };
        });
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            </View>
        )
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default LoadingScreen;
```

Comment: Are you initializing Firebase somewhere else in the code as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69666776/13130697)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj YES  I have done it in other file

Answer (score 1):

I see a few concerns/problems with the above code:

- use of `compat` is not encouraged ; Firebase explicitly stated that this is a stop-gap measure for people with large v8 code bases that need to move to v9 but want to stick with the v8 syntax -- and that the v8 syntax (and `compat`) are to be deprecated in the very near future
- though Class Components remain valid in React, as you build new code I recommend you consider moving to Function Components
- there does not seem to be any attempt in your code to shut off the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener ; this is a resource leak in your code
- it is hard to tell why that particular error is occurring ; you say that you initialize Firebase in a different file so we can't see how it is initialized
- the above code relies on the "default app" (your use of `firebase.auth()` without specifying the particular `app`) -- without knowing how you initialized Firebase we can't tell if that is "doing the right thing"
- I would encourage you to NOT rely on a "default app" but to explicitly specify the app you are invoking the Authentication service from

BTW: I have moved to using the Context API for initializing Firebase and sharing its services to the rest of my app.  You can see this pattern in the FirebaseProvider.js of the following starter project.  Feel free to use/copy as you see fit: https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore