# How to listAll items inside firebase folder react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I have a folder in Firebase storage called "dataset" where I have some PDF documents which I'm trying to display them here but it's not working please help me figure out the issue?

In below code I have write the code to get the available documents from "datase/" folder.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { storage } from "../config/firebase";
import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

function ForwardPE() {

const fetchImages = async () => {
  const storageRef = await ref(storage, "dataset");
  const result = await listAll(listRef);

  const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) => getDownloadURL(imageRef));

  return Promise.all(urlPromises);
};

const loadImages = async () => {
  const urls = await fetchImages();
  console.log(urls)
  setFiles(urls);
};

loadImages()
      
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
};

export default ForwardPE;
```

Firebase.js Code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAqW6kUwy4VGS8iBb72lXqK0v3ZnxR_Ohk",
  authDomain: "ai-web-app-1eba6.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "ai-web-app-1eba6",
  storageBucket: "ai-web-app-1eba6.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "488293461041",
  appId: "1:488293461041:web:62aec35f6d5e09a0e63910"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

export const storage = getStorage();
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
```

Console Error:
[image]

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: @Dharmaraj the files are not displaying on the page also console is showing errors I'll edit my question and add console error.

Comment: I just see `return (<> </>)`. Could the issue be in that part? It'll be best to share the complete code related to this issue

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes return has just the empty fragments also the whole code for firebase and the page where I'm trying to get the items is mentioned above there is no more code I've been trying this since few days and I can;t find any solution I have also tried to go through the firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the new Firebase Modular SDK (`v9.0.0`) that has a functional syntax and unlike the older name-spaced one. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// firebase.js

import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// ... initialise other services

export const storage = getStorage();
```

```
import { storage } from "../path/to/firebase.js"

import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

const fetchImages = async () => {
  const storageRef = await ref(storage, "dataset");
  const result = await listAll(listRef);

  const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) => getDownloadURL(imageRef));

  return Promise.all(urlPromises);
};

const loadImages = async () => {
  const urls = await fetchImages();
  console.log(urls)
  setFiles(urls);
};

loadImages()
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) for more information and refer to namespace tab.

Comment: I have copied your code but the console is still showing the same error `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Comment: Opss sorry the error*

Comment: @ImranIrshad are you sure that's the same error? The errors says you have not initialised Firebase SDK. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69666776/13130697) and create a `firebase.js` as mentioned there. Once you add your Firebase credentials then import `storage` from that file and use it in your code then it should work.

Comment: I have created firebase.js as per the code in your other answer now it shows `storage, setFiles, listRef is not defined`

Comment: @ImranIrshad if you my code in this answer, I have the line: `import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"`. Make sure you have that in yours as well. Also I've added another import that imports `storage` from that `firebase.js`. i've updated my answer with the same,.

Comment: Bro I have did the same thing but it still shows `listRef, setFiles is not defined` also console shows `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Comment: @ImranIrshad can you update your question with the latest code that you have tried? In both the files.

Comment: Just updated it please check, thank you

Comment: @ImranIrshad I cannot see `setFiles(urls);` defined in your code. Otherwise every thing seems fine, can you remove that line once and restart React server and try once ?

Comment: I did and now it just says listRef is not defined

Comment: @ImranIrshad my bad, it should be `listAll(storageRef);` and not `listRef`. It's defined right above that line

Comment: Perfect it worked thank you so very much, I see the items showing up in the console. Just the last thing how do I display them in a grid format in return?

Comment: @ImranIrshad there are plenty of libraries such as [react-grid-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery) that might be helpful.