# display data from firebase storage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have PDF documents manually uploaded to firebase storage (**dataset folder**) and I'm trying download and retrieve them in reactjs, so far I'm able to download the urls and they're showing up in console but not sure why they're not displaying in the page. Please help fixing this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { storage } from "../config/firebase";
import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

function ForwardPE() {

const fetchImages = async () => {
  const storageRef = await ref(storage, "dataset");
  const result = await listAll(storageRef);

  const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) => getDownloadURL(imageRef));

  return Promise.all(urlPromises);
};

const loadImages = async () => {
  const urls = await fetchImages();
  console.log(urls);
};

loadImages()
      
  return (
    <div className="file-grid">
      <div className="file-wrap">
        <h1>PDF FILES HERE</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default ForwardPE;
```

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore'; 
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAqW6kUwy4VGS8iBb72lXqK0v3ZnxR_Ohk",
  authDomain: "ai-web-app-1eba6.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "ai-web-app-1eba6",
  storageBucket: "ai-web-app-1eba6.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "488293461041",
  appId: "1:488293461041:web:62aec35f6d5e09a0e63910"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
export const projectFirestore = getFirestore();

export const storage = getStorage();
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
```

Comment: Are you missing code in what you provided? I don't see here you declared imageRef or where you assign URLs to anything that will displayed in your UI

Comment: @HassanAhmed I have updated the code in return I was just experimenting it myself. as far as the imgRef is concerned I got this code from my other [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936342/how-to-listall-items-inside-firebase-folder-react/73936637?noredirect=1#comment130554938_73936637(]question here) and it is not declared anywhere else also if I remove it the console doesn't download the urls and throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't share your firebase config object publicly. Now we can all access your database. I'd recommend making a new project. But this might be the solution to your question. Just a simple useState

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { storage } from "../config/firebase";
import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

function ForwardPE() {

const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);

const fetchImages = async () => {
  const storageRef = await ref(storage, "dataset");
  const result = await listAll(storageRef);

  const urlPromises = result.items.map((imageRef) => getDownloadURL(imageRef));

  return Promise.all(urlPromises);
};

const loadImages = async () => {
  const _urls = await fetchImages();
  console.log(_urls);
  setUrls(_urls);
};

loadImages()
      
  return (
    <div className="file-grid">
      <div className="file-wrap">
        {urls.map((url, index) => (
          <h1 key={index}>{url}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default ForwardPE;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip and the quick fix. I'lll create a new project.