# Accessing id token of firebase 9 in axios interceptor directly

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get the id token from firebase 9 directly in the axios interceptor? It was possible with firebase 8.

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from "../config";
import { getAuth, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";

const API = axios.create({
  responseType: "json",
  baseURL: config.ApiUrl
});

API.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const { currentUser } = auth;
  
  request.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${await currentUser.getIdToken()}`,
  };
  return request;

});
```

currentUser is null first because it is loaded async by firebase. How can I access it directly without always having the problem that the first time it crashes because the user is not loaded yet?

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that waits for `onAuthStateChanged()` to load auth state and returns a promise containing user's token. Try:

```
const getUserToken = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const token = await getIdToken(user);
        resolve(token)
      } else {
        console.log("User not logged in")
        resolve(null)
      }
      unsub();
    });
  })
}
```

```
API.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
  const token = await getUserToken();

  if (token) {
    request.headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };
  } else {
    // prompt user to login?
  }

  return request;
});
```

Make sure you have initialized Firebase SDK before using `getAuth()`. I recommend creating a different file `firebase.js`, initialize required services and exporting the instances as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666823/13130697).